# How to use php curl in place of command prompt

Tags: php

I have an issue with command line. I have to use -d 
`'{"name": "YourCompanyName", "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)"}'` 
in `php curl.I` dont understand how to do this. I thought that means data in php curl  so I used this `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Bu still I am getting this error

**"error":"missing required parameter 'name'"**

```
$api_url = 'api.callrail.com/v1/companies.json';;
$fields = array('name'=>'BobsAutoShop','time_zone'=>'Pasific Time (US & Canada)');
$ch = curl_init($api_url);
//print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Token token=\"{$api_key}\"","Content-Type: application/json"));
```

Comment: Please post your code to better explain your problem.

Comment: $api_url = 'https://api.callrail.com/v1/companies.json'; $fields = array('name'=>'BobsAutoShop','time_zone'=>'Pasific Time (US  & Canada)');$ch = curl_init($api_url);
//print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) ;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");   
  
  //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $fields_string);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Token token=\"{$api_key}\"","Content-Type: application/json"));

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `json_encode` on `$fields` before sending it in the POST body. Together with fixing the undefined `$fields_string`, this would look like:

```
$fields_string = json_encode($fields);
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could accept the answer then

Answer (score 0):

I think data should be in json format so please convert post data in json as below.

```
$api_url = 'api.callrail.com/v1/companies.json';
$fields = json_encode(array('name'=>'BobsAutoShop','time_zone'=>'Pasific Time (US & Canada)'));
$ch = curl_init($api_url); //print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) ; 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Token token=\"{$api_key}\"","Content-Type: application/json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are passing wrong variable in your code :

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

Where `$fields_string` is not defined.